Screen resolution scale in JavaFx game
I'm creating a board game in JavaFx, and it works fine in my desktop PC, with a 1920x1080 screen. When i try to open it in my Laptop (which is 1920x1080 as well, but with the default screen size at 125%), it doesn't show the elements properly anymore (their size overflows the bounds of the screen). The only way to make the app work properly is to run it on a 1920x1080 screen with default scree size at 100%
I need a way to scale the whole stage to the right resolution
This is my Main.java:
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        final double WIDTH = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        final double HEIGHT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();

        Parent board = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/board.fxml"));

        Pane innerBoard = ((Pane)board.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0));
        Assert.assertCmp(innerBoard.getId(), "BOARD");

        Scene scene = new Scene(board, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        innerBoard.setVisible(false);
        
        primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        primaryStage.show();

        
        innerBoard.setVisible(true);
 
    }

}

This is the FXML:
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane id="BOARD" fx:id="innerBoard" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="-7.0" style="-fx-background-color: #cfffd1;">
         <children>
            <!-- Lots of children -->
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</Pane>


What does "it stops working" mean?  Please describe what happens when this occurs.

@jewelsea The description was misleading, it doesn't stop working. I corrected it

Toolkit is an awt class.   You shouldn't be mixing UI toolkits.  If you want screen dimensions in JavaFX, you can get them from the JavaFX Screen (this is not related to your issue).

Do you need to "scale"?   In this context, scaling is usually a kind of transform.  Or instead, do you need to use layout managers and constraints so that the scene adapts to various window sizes?   With scaling, everything will get bigger or smaller, including text, potentially stretching items non-proportionally.   With layout management, the nodes will adjust their size and placement to available space.

To understand the difference, resize your stackoverflow window, layout management is applied. Adjust your browser zoom settings using a menu, scaling is applied.

Since you’re making your Stage fullscreen, forget about obtaining the screen size and just do Scene scene = new Scene(board);.  The Scene will fill the fullscreen Stage.  Now, how to make the board scale properly might be another matter, but it is certainly doable.

If the purpose is to scale by transform, this might be a duplicate.

I recommend you forego Pane and numeric positions and sizes.  You want your board to be capable of displaying in any resolution;  explicit positions and sizes directly contradict that.
Layouts are the best way to make your board fit into any size.
(Of course, layouts only work with rectangular board regions;  I will assume you aren’t going for something complex like a circular or hexagon-based board, or a board with winding paths.  In those cases, a Canvas may be a better choice than a Pane.)
GridPane allows setting RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints, each of which can be percentage-based.  If rows and columns have a size that is a percentage of the width of their parent, you get scaling for free.  Here is a very primitive rendition of a Monopoly board:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;

public class MonopolyBoard
extends Application {
    // Source:
    // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Store_Building_Flat_Icon_Vector.svg
    private static final String SIDE_SPACE_IMAGE_URI =
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53"
        + "/Store_Building_Flat_Icon_Vector.svg"
        + "/240px-Store_Building_Flat_Icon_Vector.svg.png";

    // Source:
    // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Car_icon_transparent.png
    private static final String CORNER_SPACE_IMAGE_URI =
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e"
        + "/Car_icon_transparent.png";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        Node[] row = new Node[11];

        row[0] = createSpace(CORNER_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        row[10] = createSpace(CORNER_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            row[i] = createSpace(SIDE_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        }
        grid.addRow(0, row);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            grid.add(createSpace(SIDE_SPACE_IMAGE_URI), 0, i);
            grid.add(createSpace(SIDE_SPACE_IMAGE_URI), 10, i);
        }

        row[0] = createSpace(CORNER_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        row[10] = createSpace(CORNER_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            row[i] = createSpace(SIDE_SPACE_IMAGE_URI);
        }
        grid.addRow(10, row);

        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(createColumnConstraints(2 / 11.0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(createColumnConstraints(1 / 11.0));
        }
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(createColumnConstraints(2 / 11.0));

        grid.getRowConstraints().add(createRowConstraints(2 / 11.0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(createRowConstraints(1 / 11.0));
        }
        grid.getRowConstraints().add(createRowConstraints(2 / 11.0));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 50 * 11, 50 * 11));
        stage.setTitle("Monopoly");
        stage.show();
    }

    private ColumnConstraints createColumnConstraints(double percentage) {
        ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        constraints.setPercentWidth(percentage * 100);
        constraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        return constraints;
    }

    private RowConstraints createRowConstraints(double percentage) {
        RowConstraints constraints = new RowConstraints();
        constraints.setPercentHeight(percentage * 100);
        constraints.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        return constraints;
    }

    private Node createSpace(String imageURI) {
        BorderPane container = new BorderPane();
        container.setStyle(
            "-fx-border-width: 1px;"
            + " -fx-border-style: solid;"
            + " -fx-background-image: url('" + imageURI + "');"
            + " -fx-background-position: center;"
            + " -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;"
            + " -fx-background-size: contain;");

        return container;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

In addition to using the percentage properties of RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints, the above code takes advantage of CSS image scaling using -fx-background-size: contain.
Resize (or maximize) the window to see the scaling at work.  Obviously, if it were fullscreen, the same scaling would apply.
